# Show result of conditional operation?

Tags: java, android

It's my first approach with Andorid Studio.
And I'm developing my first app.

Basically i need to know how to show the "risultato" .

I leave the code below.

```
    if (somma<=5){
        String sommaRisultato= "numero piccolo";
    }else if (somma>5 && somma<7){
        String sommaRisultato= "numero medio";
    }else if (somma>=8){
        String sommaRisultato= "numero alto";
    }

    txtRis.setText(String.valueOf("il risultato: " + somma)); //Here only shows somma value, I need sommaRisultato
```

Comment: Declare just one `String sommaRisultato` outside the entire `if-block` and re-assign values according to the *conditions*.

Comment: `setText("il risultato: " + soma + ", " + somaRisultato)` note there is no need for `String.valueOf` if you already have a string (`"il risultatto..."`) since the result of using `+` is a string

Comment: When you declare a variable, they only exist within the contex ``{ String x = "known"; } x is unknown outside``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the variable out of the `if` statements :

```
String sommaRisultato = null;
if (somma<=5){
    sommaRisultato= "numero piccolo";
}else if (somma>5 && somma<7){
    sommaRisultato= "numero medio";
}else if (somma>=8){
    sommaRisultato= "numero alto";
}
txtRis.setText(String.valueOf("il risultato: " + sommaRisultato));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the variable `sommaRisultato` individually inside of the if-block. This way `sommaRisultato` is not accessible outside of your if-statement. To be able to access it later, declare it beforehand (and maybe create an empty string literal as default case, or whatever you like) and change the value it refers to:

```
String sommaRisultato = "";

if (somma <= 5){
    sommaRisultato = "numero piccolo";
} else if (somma > 5 && somma < 7){
    sommaRisultato = "numero medio";
} else if (somma >= 8){
    sommaRisultato = "numero alto";
}

txtRis.setText("il risultato: " + sommaRisultato);
```

Also, you should not need the `String.valueOf` call, because now you concatenate two strings, which makes another string already.